# state channel between smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

In my scenario, there are data sellers and data buyers which might be persons or organizations.

I would like to create a smart contract for data seller and another smart contract for data buyer where the smart contrast of buyer negotiate with the smart contract of several sellers to buy data automatically and without human innervation.

After that, payment and sharing data are carried out through off-chain or state channel. 
I was wondering if you help me how can I do that.
regards,